# How to fix TypeError: t is null, when trying to replace entire <HTML>?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, pug

I am currently trying to replace an entire page with AJAX. I 'cannot' simply redirect to another url according to my assignment for whatever reason.

My node.js server has index.pug.
The submit form is meant to load the same page again but replace the entire HTML file, after the POST request is processed.
I know I could simply just replace the  but I would like to simply just render my page with any replacement.

I've tried to replace it with $("body").html(res) which doesn't give the error but doesn't replace the  as I need, and $("head").html(res) also provides the same error.

I get this, when I try to use $("head").html(res):

```
TypeError: t is null
```

pug:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Simple Upload Example
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js' )
    script.
      $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#eventForm').submit(function (e) {
      //Do two sends.
      e.preventDefault();
      var username = ($('#username')[0]);
      var password = ($('#password')[0]);
      var files = ($('#image-input')[0].files);
      // Append the files to the formData.
      var fd = new FormData();
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      fd.append('photos[]', file, file.name);
      }
      fd.append('password',password.value);
      fd.append('username',username.value);
      $.ajax({
      url: '/',
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function (res) {
      console.log("Success");
      $(document).html(res);
      },
      error: function () {
      console.log("Failure");
      }
      });
      });
      });
  body
    form#eventForm(method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data')
      input#image-input(type='file', accept='image/png, image/jpeg')
      input#username(type='text')
      input#password(type='text')
      input(type='submit')
    h1=message
```

js

```
var express = require('express');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var uuidv5 = require('uuid/v5');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render(__dirname + '/index.pug', {
        message: 'hi'
    });
});

//Create a new ID.
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var fields = [];
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req);

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {
        file.path = '.' + '/uploads/' + file.name;
    });

    //Push field onto an array
    form.on('field', function (name, value) {
        fields.push('"' + name + '"' + ':' + '"' + value + '"');
    });

    form.on('file', function (name, file) {
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });

    //Convert array into form
    form.on('end', function () {
        var photo_id = uuidv5('http://example.com/hello', uuidv5.URL);
        var str = '{' + fields.toString() + '}'
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(str)

        fs.mkdirSync(__dirname + '/users/' + jsonData.username, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });

        fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/users/' + jsonData.username + '/jsonData.json', str, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });

    res.render(__dirname + '/index.pug', {
        message: 'hiya'
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: "doesn't replace the as I need"  You missed something